# Laravel to operate device HHC-N8I8O

Tags: php

I have purchased this device HHC-N8I8O.

I want to know if we can give direct commands from laravel to turn on or off a relay?

i have got the manual and some software, it works from software with ip 192.168.0.105 and port 5000

but i want to control it from my own software and don't know how i can send commands to this device?

below is the manual with some information but i don't understand how i can use this?

```
Command description:
Commands are sent in character.
Control one relay
Open the first relay.
Send: on1
Return: on1
Turn off the first relay.
Send: off1
Return: off1
The 2-8 way control is the same as the above instructions.

Read relay status
Send: read
Return: relay 00000001 (state of 8-way relay, 1 relay suction, 0 relay unlock, 1 relay suction, 2-8 relay unlock)

Control all relays
Send: all00000011
Return: relay00000011
```

All is the control of all relay instructions, the latter 8 control, 1 means suction, 0 means loosening the above instruction means the first way suction with the second way, 3-8 way loosening. This instruction returns to the state of the relay after execution. The state return information of the relay is the same as that of the read instruction.

Delay control
For example, if the relay is to be pulled in after 2 seconds, the following instructions can be issued.

Send: on1:02
Return: on1

In the above instructions, the relay will be released after 2 seconds, on1: the relay to be controlled, followed by a delay time of up to 99 seconds, for example on2:12 means that the second relay will be released after 12 seconds. The other 2-8 way control is the same as above.

Read switch input

Send: input
Return: input00000001
Input followed by 00000001, 1 means switching input, 0 means no switching input, 8-way switching input state, the above instructions indicate that the first way has switching input, 2-8 channels have no switching input.

Test instructions.
The device works on the TCP server.

How does it work through TCP?

Read command to read relay status, input command to read discrete inputs. Relay Control: on1 or off1, On2 or Off2 and so on

Comment: If you have a way in Laravel to make a TCP connection and send and receive text on that connection, then you can control this. If you have a way from Laravel to invoke a Unix command-line tool like netcat (nc) or socat, then you could call nc or socat from Laravel to control this.

Comment: @Spiff, small clarification, from examples I see this device use UDP, not TCP

Comment: @RomeoNinov I've seen some documentation saying it supports both TCP and UDP. https://www.thanksbuyer.com/8-channel-ip-network-relay-controller-rs485-to-ethernet-switch-quantity-controller-with-shell-68711

Comment: @Spiff, my link (in answer) use UDP. But of course it is possible board support TCP also. :)

Comment: our device support tcp/udp, can be configured to use udp, but we prefer to use tcp

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [info](https://github.com/gabrielgbs97/hhc_n8i8op_mqtt/blob/master/README.md) you need to send string (`on1` for example) to IP of the board and port 5000 (UDP package).

In Linux this will be something like:

```
printf "on1" | nc -q 1 -un 192.168.0.105 5000
```

P.S. Here is a code Bard generate for me:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

class UdpController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request)
    {
        $ip = $request->input('ip');
        $port = $request->input('port');
        $message = $request->input('message');

        try {
            $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
            socket_connect($socket, $ip, $port);
            socket_send($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0);
            socket_close($socket);

            Log::info('Message sent successfully:', ['ip' => $ip, 'port' => $port, 'message' => $message]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error sending message:', ['exception' => $e]);
        }

        return response('Message sent successfully', 200);
    }
}
```

To use this controller, you would first need to create a route that calls the send method. For example, you could add the following route to your `routes/web.php` file:
PHP

```
Route::post('/udp/send', 'UdpController@send');
```

and then generate post request:

```
POST /udp/send HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "ip": "192.168.0.105",
    "port": 5000,
    "message": "on1"
}
```